# fullcalendar changing color on move

Tags: jquery, css, json, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar with entries for several different users. I have successfully made each user's calendar entry a different color. This all works, except if I drag a calendar entry (move) to another date, the color changes back to default.

json looks like this

```
{  
   "events":[  
      {  
         "title":"tkt[14411]",
         "start":"2015-07-09T06:00:00.196-0500",
         "end":"2015-07-09T08:00:00.196-0500",
         "id":"7",
         "userID":"1",
         "calColor":"#ff0000",
         "className":"ticketSrc_1",
         "custom":"test text here"
      },
      {  
         "title":"tkt[14412]",
         "start":"2015-07-11T06:00:00.196-0500",
         "end":"2015-07-11T08:00:00.196-0500",
         "id":"7",
         "userID":"2",
         "calColor":"#ffff00",
         "className":"ticketSrc_2",
         "custom":"test text here"
      }      
   ],
   "error":"0"
}
```

my code to add the events and change the color for each is this:

```
// remove duplicate events
for(var i=0;i<=json.events.length-1;i++){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar("removeEvents",json.events[i].id);
}

// set colors for each user
$.when(
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar("addEventSource",json)
  ).done(function(){
      var cname="";
            for(var i=0;i<=json.events.length-1;i++){
                cname=".ticketSrc_"+json.events[i].userID;  
                $(cname).css("background",json.events[i].calColor);
            }                     
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to pass a "color" parameter in the json

```
{  
   "events":[  
      {  
         "title":"tkt[14411]",
         "start":"2015-07-09T06:00:00.196-0500",
         "end":"2015-07-09T08:00:00.196-0500",
         "id":"7",
         "userID":"1",
         "color":"#ff0000",
         "className":"ticketSrc_1",
         "custom":"test text here"
      },
      {  
         "title":"tkt[14412]",
         "start":"2015-07-11T06:00:00.196-0500",
         "end":"2015-07-11T08:00:00.196-0500",
         "id":"7",
         "userID":"2",
         "color":"#ffff00",
         "className":"ticketSrc_2",
         "custom":"test text here"
      }      
   ],
   "error":"0"
}
```